# AWS lambda, Unable to import a module(in package) (written in Cython)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, cython

I am trying to import [python-dependency-injector](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector) package within lambda function.

To run lambda function, I have zipped my project contents together with packages in /opt/anaconda3/envs/.../python3.9/site-packages to deploy a fast-api(with mangum) app.

Use of any other packages works fine, but weirdly using this package (written in Cython) results in below error :\

{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'main': cannot import name 'providers' from 'dependency_injector' (/var/task/dependency_injector/**init**.py)", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "requestId": "5c63c01b-5be1-4481-adf8-691167cb54bd", "stackTrace": []}

I am not sure whether this is a known issue when using packages written in Cython or there are any workarounds.

- I have also tried manually importing the package (that was in site-packages) within a newly created EC2 (AWS linux) and also my local (Mac)
- Without importing this specific package, everything else works fine.

Would really appreciate if someone can guide me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Running into the same problem after upgrading from Python 3.8 to 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can use **docker bundling** with a Python 3.9 image and the next command:

```
pip3.9 install --platform=manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -r requirements-dependency_injector_layer.txt -t /asset-output/python
```

Using CDK makes this task very straightforward:

```
dependency_injector_layer = lambda_.LayerVersion(
    scope=self,
    id="id",
    layer_version_name="name",
    code=lambda_.Code.from_asset(
        str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("dependencies").resolve()),
        bundling=BundlingOptions(
            image=lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9.bundling_image,
            command=[
                "bash", "-c",
                "pip3.9 install --platform=manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -r requirements-dependency_injector_layer.txt -t /asset-output/python"
                " && cp -au . /asset-output/python",
            ]
        )
    ),
    compatible_runtimes=[
        lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
    ],
    removal_policy=RemovalPolicy.RETAIN,
)
```

Taken from this [Github issue](https://github.com/ets-labs/python-dependency-injector/issues/543#issuecomment-1875649178).

Comment: I managed to create a lambda-layer using this command as you suggest: 
pip install --platform=manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all: -r requirements.txt -t .\python\. Without --platfrom argument it was not working. After installing depenencies with this command, my CDK proyect picks code inside python directory and creates a layer for the lambda.